# How to store boolean value in jsonb column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I'm getting a checkbox value from my form like this

```
<%= f.label 'Most Popular', class: "form-label" %>
                    <%= check_box_tag "price_template[preferences][pcb_budget_options][][most_popular]",
                                        true,
                                        f.object.preferences.dig("pcb_budget_options", index, "most_popular") %>
```

And the params I am permitting is like this

```
params.require(:price_template).permit(:currency_id,
                                         :program_id,
                                         :active,
                                         :default,
                                         country_ids: [],
                                         preferences: [budget_options:     [:amount, :most_popular, :text],
                                                       pcb_budget_options: [:amount, :most_popular]])
```

and it stored in DB like this

```
   {
  "budget_options"=>[
    {"amount"=>"1.0", "text"=>"budget options"},
    {"amount"=>"2.0", "most_popular"=>"true", "text"=>"budget options"},
    {"amount"=>"3.0", "text"=>"budget options"}
  ],
  "pcb_budget_options"=>[
    {"amount"=>"1.0"},
    {"amount"=>"0.0"},
    {"amount"=>"-1.0", "most_popular"=>"true"}
  ]
}
```

but the **most_popular** value is stored here is in **string** format but I want to store it as a **boolean**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in `jsonb` it will be always save as a "string" in the DB.

You can create your own serializer to parse the jsonb as you want or if only the boolean part matter for you, you can create a method in your model like this

```
class Mymodel
  def budget_most_popular
    ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(preferences["budget_options"]["most_popular"])
  end

  def pcb_budget_most_popular
    ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(preferences["pcb_budget_options"]["most_popular"])
  end
end
```

So anywhere in your code you can get a real boolean value by calling this method.

Imagine you have the following record

```
$> MyModel.first
<MyModel:0x029I23EZ
id: 1,
name: "foo",
preferences: {
  "budget_options" => 
    [ 
      { "amount"=>"10", "most_popular"=>"true", "text"=>"" },
      {"amount"=>"0.0", "text"=>""}, {"amount"=>"0.0", "text"=>""}
    ],
  "pcb_budget_options"=>
    [
      {"amount"=>"20", "most_popular"=>"false"}, {"amount"=>"0.0"},
      {"amount"=>"0.0"}
    ]
}
...
```

And somewhere in your code you need to check if `budget_option` is `most_popular`

```
class MyModelController

   def show
     @mymodel = MyModel.first

     if @mymodel.budget_most_popular
       render "template/most_popular"
     else
       render "template/less_popular"
     end
   end
end
```

Since in our last record `budget_options` as `most_popular` set as `'true'` our model method `budget_most_popular` will cast this `'true'`to return a boolean `true` so our show will render the `most_popular` template

[Here is an interesting blog article about the jsonb with Rails](https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: i did not get it both functions return true can you please elaborate bit more

Comment: we can use JSON.parse but i will need extra cost

Comment: The `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast` will cast your string into a real boolean value. If you do `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast('false')` it will return `false` and if your pass `'true'` it will return `true`. So in your code whenever you will need to have the `most_popular` value of your object you will just to call one of this method to get a real boolean

Comment: yeah I know this but it will increase the run time while fetching data

Comment: JSON supports boolean values. The problem is that the form gives you a string (because *everything* comes out of forms as strings) so convert the strings to whatever they're supposed to be before putting anything into the database. Normally AR does this for you because it knows the column types but it has no way of knowing what the values inside a blob of JSON are supposed to be.

Comment: @muistooshort AR ? what does it mean and you mean that the only solution is that we have to convert this before saving it into the database. ?

Comment: "AR" means ActiveRecord. And yes, I think you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: @HumayunNaseer no whatever the type of your jsonb's element it will be always save in the DB as a string. You have no other choice than parsing your jsonb whenever you want to use it. It will not add a huge running time except if your jsonb is really big and messy.

Comment: please read comment of @muistooshort i think he is right i saw some examples