# Convert true-false strings to boolean & Skip the rest in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hash that contains 2 arrays of hashes

```
h = {
  "budget_options"=>[
    {"amount"=>"1.0", "text"=>"budget options"},
    {"amount"=>"2.0", "most_popular"=>"true", "text"=>"budget options"},
    {"amount"=>"3.0", "text"=>"budget options"}
  ],
  "pcb_budget_options"=>[
    {"amount"=>"1.0"},
    {"amount"=>"0.0"},
    {"amount"=>"-1.0", "most_popular"=>"true"}
  ]
}
```

I just want to convert **"most_popular"** value from string to **boolean** I tried to do this but it ends up with n3 time complexity.

Is there a built-in method to do this?
Any kind of help will be appriciated.

Comment: Is the nested structure always structured in the same way and are the keys are always named the same? Or does the solution be generic and be able to transform stringified booleans values no matter how the hash is nested?

Comment: Are you really still on Ruby on Rails version 5? I am asking because Ruby on Rails 6 added [`deep_transform_values`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Hash#deep_transform_values-instance_method) which would make this task much easier.

Comment: IMHO this smells like something you should actually be handling with a model attribute / setter. You're not modeling the domain very well if you have to resort to hash manipulation.

Comment: @spickermann yes unfortunately our project is still on rails 5 and yes the hash will be the same way just the most_popular boolean value can be attached with any of three hashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want.  I have not calculated the O of it.
I used the Marshal#dump/load trick to do a deep copy of the object before manipulating it.

```
mp = "most_popular"
obj = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h))
obj.each_key {|k| obj[k].each {|v| v[mp] = v[mp] == "true" ? true : false if v[mp] }}
```

Also see Cary's comment below for a slightly more terse version of the inner block.

Comment: You might write the inner block `{|v| v[mp] = v[mp] == "true" if v.key?(mp) }`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, that works as well.  I might prefer include? over key? but that's just a person choice.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland your answer is also good and I upvote both of the answers but I'm going to accept this because nPn is the first one to submit the answer. Thank you guys  you help me a lot

Comment: Humayun, I agree this is a good answer, deserving of my upvote. The [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html) methods are quite handy for making deep copies.

Comment: Actually, first I want to do it like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794593/how-to-store-boolean-value-in-jsonb-column/71795128?noredirect=1#comment126877410_71795128

and after I fail to find any solution then i want to do in this way 
can you please have a look ?

Comment: so at the end can anyone please told me  that how this syntax works ? 
v[mp] = v[mp] == "true"

Comment: and why do you make a shallow copy of hash? although we can perform that action directly on hash

Answer (score 2):

If you do not wish to mutate `h` you can write

```
h.transform_values do |arr|
  arr.map do |g|
    g.merge({})
     .tap { |f| f["most_popular"] = f["most_popular"]=="true" if f.key?("most_popular") }
  end
end
  #=> {
  #     "budget_options"=>[
  #       {"amount"=>"1.0", "text"=>"budget options"},
  #       {"amount"=>"2.0", "most_popular"=>true, "text"=>"budget options"},
  #       {"amount"=>"3.0", "text"=>"budget options"}
  #     ],
  #     "pcb_budget_options"=>[
  #       {"amount"=>"1.0"},
  #       {"amount"=>"0.0"},
  #       {"amount"=>"-1.0", "most_popular"=>true}
  #     ]
  #   }
```

The purpose of `g.merge({})` is to avoid mutating the inner hashes. See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) and [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).

Comment: Actually, first I want to do it like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794593/how-to-store-boolean-value-in-jsonb-column/71795128?noredirect=1#comment126877410_71795128

and after I fail to find any solution then i want to do in this way 
can you please have a look ?